# Журавлики или журавликов?

Tags: склонение

Однажды на форуме мне попался такой вопрос. Речь шла о бумажных журавликах-оригами, которых в Японии делают на счастье. И нужно было сказать: "Я делаю журавликов". Но ведь бумажные журавлики - предмет неодушевленный, поэтому, по идее, правильнее было бы сказать: "Я делаю журавлики". Однако это режет слух - чаще о них говорят как об одушевленных объектах.
А как будет правильно с точки зрения русского языка: журавликов или журавлики?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Я делаю журавликов.**

В данном случае все просто.
Грамматическая одушевленность "наследуется" от основного объекта, который олицетворяется в его копии или модели.

Сложнее, когда название переносится на объект, который не является такой копией или моделью.
Например, "запустил бумажного змея" или "запустил бумажный змей"?
"Закрепил крокодила" или "крокодил" (застежка)?
"Выпил медведя" или "медведь" (коктейль)?

Грамматика не дает однозначного ответа, но все-таки даже в этих случаях склоняется к одушевленности.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: я делаю журавликов.

Грамматическое значение категории одушевленности не всегда совпадает с семантическим значением, например, кукла - это, с точки зрения грамматики,  одушевленное существительное.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Московский клуб оригами представит на выставке как простых журавликов, так и сложные  конструкции.

В те же годы тысячи детей во всем мире складывали из бумаги журавликов…